# Sending data from VC++ to Visual Basic in a .NET framework

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++

I'm having a heck of a time figuring this out, the tutorials I found on the web are not complete or are for VB 6.0 (obsolete in some cases).  On the C++ side I have the following ::

.....
hwndExternalApplication = FindWindow(NULL, L"Dromocast Client"); 
SendMessage(hwndExternalApplication, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)"Hello");
.....

"Dromocast Client" is my visual basic application, and I checked to make sure it's not NULL.  In fact I get made sure I'm getting some data on the VB side.  On my Visual Basic side I have the following ::

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    Select Case (m.Msg)
        Case WM_SETTEXT
            Dim strTemp As String
            strTemp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(m.LParam)
            MessageBox.Show("GOT THE MESSAGE, SETTING LOCAL VARIABLE")
    End Select

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

When I send the data over it's garbage, meaning strTemp comes out as all these chinese characters, and my title bar on the visual basic program gets garbled with a bunch of chinese characters as well.  My guess is my "SendMessage" is written wrong, or I'm doing something silly, but I have no idea what.  I'm not a windows programmer so I'm kinda trying to figure this stuff out by googling....any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `(LPARAM)"Hello"` to `(LPARAM)L"Hello"` . I think .net expects string to be widechar.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  I'm not sure what I was doing wrong originally, but it wasn't working.  Cleaned up my code a bit,removed dll's function calls I wasn't using and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your C string isn't a Unicode string, it's an [ANSI](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/31/144893.aspx) string. Try using [PtrToStringANSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringansi.aspx) instead of PtrToStringUnicode